# Why wont this accordion collapse?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-accordion

I have the following accordion in my view.
I can't get it to collapse and I thought it's default behavior is collapsed.
(When I run it from visual studio, it does check all sub-items, though from here , it does'nt.)

The Markup for the accordion behaviour is generated from within an action using C#.
Thanks.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>

  .tree li {
   margin: 0px 0;
   list-style-type: none;
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px 5px 0px 5px;
  }

   .tree li::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    right: auto;
    left: -20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 50px;
   }

   .tree li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    right: auto;
    left: -20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
   }

   .tree li a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   }

  /*Remove connectors before root*/
  .tree > ul > li::before, .tree > ul > li::after {
   border: 0;
  }
  /*Remove connectors after last child*/
  .tree li:last-child::before {
   height: 30px;
  }

  /*Time for some hover effects*/
  /*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
  .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover + ul li a {
   background: #dd4814;
   color: #ffffff;
   border: 1px solid #dd4814;
  }
   /*Connector styles on hover*/
   .tree li a:hover + ul li::after,
   .tree li a:hover + ul li::before,
   .tree li a:hover + ul::before,
   .tree li a:hover + ul ul::before {
    border-color: #dd4814;
   }

  .tree-checkbox {
   margin: 4px !important;
  }


  .tree:before {
   border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
   bottom: 16px;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: -21px;
   width: 1px;
   z-index: 1;
   border: none;
  }

  .tree ul:after {
   border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
   content: "";
   height: 20px;
   left: -29px;
   position: absolute;
   right: auto;
   top: 37px;
   width: 34px;
   border: none;
  }

  *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .tree {
   overflow: auto;
   padding-left: 0px;
   position: relative;
  }


  li {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 90%;
  }

  li {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 90%;
  }

  b {
   width: 10%;
   display: block;
  }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; height: 1800px; ">
  <div class="panel-heading panel-head" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 400px; height: 40px; background-color: gainsboro;">Security Permissions</div>
  <div class="panel-body" id="Permissions" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 400px; height: 1800px;  background-color: ghostwhite;">
   <form action="/Security/Index" method="post">
    <div class="tree" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; height: 1200px; ">
     <ul class="nav nav-list" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#Psubmenu_1" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="pull-left">
         <input name="MM_IsPermitted1" class="MMtree-checkbox" id="MM_IsPermitted1" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1">
         <input name="MM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
        </span>
        Admin
       </span>
       <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="Psubmenu_1" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <li>
         <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu_1" data-toggle="collapse">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox" id="SM_IsPermitted1" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
          Debtors-Creditors
         </span>
        </li>
        <li>
         <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#Ssubmenu_1" data-toggle="collapse">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox" id="SM_IsPermitted1" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
          Users
         </span>
         <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="Ssubmenu_1" style="padding-left: 40px;">
          <li>
           <span class="accordion-heading" data-target="#Ssubmenu_11" data-toggle="collapse">
            <input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox" id="SM_IsPermitted10" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1">
            <input name="SM_IsPermitted10" type="hidden" value="false">
            new subby tst3
           </span>
          </li>
         </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
         <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#Ssubmenu_1" data-toggle="collapse">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox" id="SM_IsPermitted1" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1">
          <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
          Contacts
         </span>

        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#Psubmenu_2" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="pull-left">
         <input name="MM_IsPermitted2" class="MMtree-checkbox" id="MM_IsPermitted2" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2">
         <input name="MM_IsPermitted2" type="hidden" value="false">
        </span>
        Home
       </span>
       <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="Psubmenu_2" style="padding-left: 20px;"></ul>
      </li>

     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-lg-9"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-3">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" type="submit">
       Submit
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function ()
  {
   $("#accordion-heading").accordion({

    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    //Set the active accordion tab to none
    active: 'none'
   })
   $(".subtree-checkbox").click(function (e)
   {

    //prevent the accordion collapse behaviour on the sub levels
    e.stopPropagation();

   });

   $(".MMtree-checkbox").click(function (e)
   {
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemId = $(this).attr("iid");
    var ischecked = $(this).prop('checked');

    //CheckAllChildren();
    //checkbox is an input,..find all inputs with iid matching that of the checked/clicked on checkbox
    var abc = $('input[iid^=' + itemId + ']');
    var txt = "";

    $(abc).each(function (index, element)
    {
     txt = element.id + txt; //shows all the inputs with the name(text) where iid = the iid of the clicked on Checkbox input
     $(this).prop("checked", ischecked);
    });
   });

 
  });

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add below line in your code

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This will solve your problem. Marked as Answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: No answer came. Some explanation may be appropriate. I downvoted this acknowledged answer for lack of quality, because it did not work for me and I have no idea why.. Also, an answer stated like this does not give any assurances, that the above includes properly combine with other scripts on a page.